# How to recover data from broken ubuntu partition?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

My ubuntu partition got corrupted for some reason, so I created another partition and reinstalled ubuntu there. Now I'm trying to recover data from my old partition(I don't need it all, only few git repos). I tried testdisk, but it shows "Can't open filesystem. Filesystem seems damaged". Photorec recovered some files, but it's kinda hard to put everything together(for some reason Photorec puts files from same directory to different directories), so I want to  try to manually recover folder structure only as last resort. Is there any other ways I can try to recover data(ideally only data from specific folder)?

Comment: Did you `fsck` or *file-system* check your partition.   Assuming the drive is healthy, I'd expect normal operation after a `fsck` was done (ie. errors detected & fixed).  The `fsck` is best done using a *live* system (ie. installation media and using the "*Try Ubuntu*" option)

Comment: I hope you did not overwrite the damaged partition. Overwritten data is unrecoverable. If the data is important to you, stop using the disk immediately and take it to a data recovery specialist.  photorec and testdisk are advanced utilities and can actually cause more data loss. In the future, back up your important data because without backups it's not a question *if* you will lose your data, but *when*. Hardware fails all the time and even the best of us make mistakes

Answer (score 0):

If you can still login then open a terminal and type `sudo gparted`
If you cannot, which is more likely, make a bootable USB with gparted.
It has an *attempt data recovery* under the *Device* menu.
This is a **very** slow process. Backup whatever you can first. You probably only have a 5% chance of recovery I am afraid.